# Paste images using right click mouse (paste option)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I developed a file input that allows me to select / drag files.

Is there a way to paste an image or file using the right mouse button, paste option in the input?

[DEMO Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pe5uen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdnd.directive.ts)

**Code**

```
 // Dragover listener
  @HostListener('dragover', ['$event']) onDragOver(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.fileOver = true;
  }

  // Dragleave listener
  @HostListener('dragleave', ['$event']) public onDragLeave(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.fileOver = false;
  }

  // Drop listener
  @HostListener('drop', ['$event']) public ondrop(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.fileOver = false;
    let files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
    if (files.length > 0) {
      this.fileDropped.emit(files);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You mean by right click paste or right click `->` select paste option?